# Upper bound on the Bitcoin transaction size

Tags: transactions, transaction-weight

Assume that I want to store some arbitrary data on the Bitcoin blockchain via a single transaction.

**Question**: Is there any upper bound on the size of data I want to send via a single transaction?

--

*Edit:* I need to know how much "arbitrary data" I can store in the blockchain via a single transaction. Is there any upper bound on the field of the transaction that allows "some arbitrary data" to be stored in it?

Comment: @RaghavSood Thanks for the link provided. The main difference, here is that I need to know how much "arbitrary data" in the transaction data field I can send to the blockchain.

Comment: @user153465 https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78572/60443

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29554/explanation-of-what-an-op-return-transaction-looks-like

Comment: as comment, cause answer section is already closed... I think it is only a duplicate, if within the idea of "OP_RETURN". But the original post didn't ask explicitly for OP_RETURN. Just how to put arbitrary data into the blockchain. One could think of creating a P2SH transaction, which has a script limit of 520 Bytes, and the tx would have many inputs/outputs, up to tx maxsize (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22tx.22_messages).

Answer (score 1):

Typically people will store arbitrary data in a separate output in a transaction beginning with `OP_RETURN`.

Any output with this OP code will be considered [invalid or provably unspendable](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_RETURN), but will still exist as part of the blockchain.

As mentioned in [this thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/78579/85140) Bitcoin-core options will allow for up to `80 bytes` of arbitrary data by default. It is worth noting that `80 bytes` is simply a default value. Nodes can change the `-datacarriersize` parameter to manually adjust the limit for the acceptance of larger or smaller amounts of data. For example, [this transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d29c9c0e8e4d2a9790922af73f0b8d51f0bd4bb19940d9cf910ead8fbe85bc9b) is `1155 bytes` with `983 bytes` of arbitrary data and has still been validated into the network.

The [history](http://www.talkcrypto.org/blog/2016/12/30/op_return-40-to-80-bytes/) of the default value is actually quite interesting and has been switched around a [few](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3737) [times](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5286) throughout Bitcoin's existance.